# How to set capabilities of a universe in Java 3d?

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, java-3d

How can I set the bounds on a SimpleUniverse instance created with a canvas3d object?

I tried the code below, but I get either a "Capability not set exception" if I try to set the bounds and a "Restricted access exception" if I try to set the capability to write bounds.

Here's my code:

```
GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
Canvas3D canvas3d = new Canvas3D(config);
SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse(canvas3d);
ViewingPlatform viewPlatform = universe.getViewingPlatform();

// Below line throws RestricedAccessException
viewPlatform.setCapability(ViewingPlatform.ALLOW_BOUNDS_WRITE); 
// I want to set the bounds, thus the need for the capability above
viewPlatform.setBounds(bounds);
```

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  Rather than set up the universe like this:

```
GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
Canvas3D canvas3d = new Canvas3D(config);

SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse(canvas3d);
```

I set up the `ViewingPlatform` by itself, then created the universe with it:

```
GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
Canvas3D canvas3d = new Canvas3D(config);

ViewingPlatform viewingPlatform = new ViewingPlatform();
viewingPlatform.setCapability(ViewingPlatform.ALLOW_BOUNDS_WRITE);
viewingPlatform.setBounds(bounds);
Viewer viewer = new Viewer(canvas3d);    

SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse(viewingPlatform, viewer);
```